# VB Getting the selected item from a List View

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have a list view with two columns and I'd like to be able to save the value of the leftmost column for the selected row, or even better make it so that once the user clicks on either the right or left column of any given row, the entire row selects and not only the field that was clicked.

However I'm struggling to get the field saved which is more crucial than the row highlighting.

In a list box it would be

```
string = listbox1.selecteditem.tostring
```

However this doesn't seem to work for the list view. It won't even let me put "Selecteditem" and instead requires I put selecteditems, however this doesn't seem to do what I want either.

When I use the code:

```
string = ListView1.SelectedItems.ToString
```

I get the result of

```
string = "System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection"
```

Despite the selected field actually being "EGG".

I need to have two columns so can't switch to using a listbox, although that seems like it would be the easier solution.
When I tried googling this question I could only find things for C#

Comment: Set FullRowSelect on. SelectedItems.ToString refers to the collection of selected items. SelectedItems(0).Text refers to the first selected item's text property.

Comment: `strPicked = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text`  as the result tells you, its a collection so you have to indicate which one you want

Comment: @Mort Right thanks! I figured it'd be something simple like that but I couldn't figure it out, post as an answer instead of a comment so i can make it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set FullRowSelect on to get the entire row to select.

`SelectedItems.ToString` refers to the collection of selected items.

`SelectedItems(0).Text` refers to the first selected item's text property.

Comment: How would I get the value of the item in the second column of the selected row? selecteditems(1).tostring doesn't work, I'm guessing I have to add a .subitems somewhere but where?

Comment: SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text <- or whichever index you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I tried exactly that only I used .tostring instead of .text and it was just giving me the value of the selected item not the subitem

Comment: Another question, sorry. I have code so that when a button is pressed, the value of the selected item is saved as a variable. However if the user clicks the button without first selecting a row, the program crashes. Is there a way to avoid this? I tried using an if statement to say, if the selecteditems(0).text = "" then to exit the sub, but that didn't work. Is there a way to automatically select a row on form load?

Comment: You're getting your value for money here! :D Try something on these lines: If Not yourListView.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't think these two questions were worth making a whole new post about, so I just asked here hoping you'd see before my deadline for these forms :D Thanks for the help man